# Supporting Partial Updates in OpenGL ES

Tags: 3d, opengl-es

I am writing a simple compositing application (for Android) which needs to support partial updates. On Windows, we could have used [IDXGISwapChain1::Present1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_2/nf-dxgi1_2-idxgiswapchain1-present1) to achieve the same because it takes the dirty rects to update in DXGI_PRESENT_PARAMETERS.

However, I am facing issues finding an equivalent API in OpenGL-ES. In my attempt to find an equivalent APIs, I discovered [KHR_swap_buffers_with_damage](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/extensions/KHR/EGL_KHR_swap_buffers_with_damage.txt) and [KHR_partial_update](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/extensions/KHR/EGL_KHR_partial_update.txt), however they are not giving me the expected output on my scenario.

My scenario is that:

1. Clear background with input color, eg - Blue
2. Draw a rectangle of input size and color via partial update. In partial update, the blue background should not disappear while in full update (eg- eglSwapBuffers), the background will disappear.

Both the above APIs make the background disappear, which seems like a full update to me despite passing the dirty rects. I have also ensured that both the APIs returned EGL_True and had no error.

I have had some success with using [eglSurfaceAttrib](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/sdk/docs/man/html/eglSurfaceAttrib.xhtml) and set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR behavior to EGL_BUFFER_PRESERVED and calling eglSwapBuffers. But it seems more like a hack to what I want.

Can anyone point me to the correct direction on how I can support partial updates for my case?

EDIT: Some code to give how I am using the API:

```
if( eglSurfaceAttrib == nullptr ) // Get the function. Function pointers have same name as the function itself for clarity.
{
    //typedef bool( *demo1 ) ( EGLDisplay dpy, EGLSurface surface, EGLint rects, EGLint n_rects );
    eglSurfaceAttrib = ( demo1 )eglGetProcAddress("eglSurfaceAttrib");
}

if( done == false ) // Set surface property to EGL_BUFFER_DESTROYED
{
    eglSurfaceAttrib(display, window, EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR, EGL_BUFFER_DESTROYED );
    done = true;
}

EGLint val;
eglQuerySurface(display, window, EGL_BUFFER_AGE_KHR, &val );

if( eglSetDamageRegionKHR == nullptr )
{
    // rect and numRect are parameters to this function.
    // typedef bool( *demo ) ( EGLDisplay dpy, EGLSurface surface, const EGLint *rects, EGLint n_rects );
    eglSetDamageRegionKHR = ( demo )eglGetProcAddress( "eglSetDamageRegionKHR" );
}

eglSetDamageRegionKHR ( display, window, rects, numRect );

// Do rendering needed to get N'th frame from (N-2)nd frame (i.e. (N-age)'th frame)
// Throw error if eglSetDamageRegionKHR failed and return the error.

if( eglSwapBuffersWithDamageKHR == nullptr )
    eglSwapBuffersWithDamageKHR = ( demo )eglGetProcAddress("eglSwapBuffersWithDamageKHR");
    
eglSwapBuffersWithDamageKHR ( display, window, rects, numRect );
```

I am passing a single rect with value ( 0, 0, 600, 600 ) [as ( x, y, width, height )] with (0,0) being bottom left corner of screen and Y axis going upwards. All updates are confined to this region only.

Comment: Are you factoring in the pipelining (`EGL_BUFFER_AGE_KHR`) of the window surfaces? Remember that when you do partial rendering without preserve you are not rendering on top of the contents of frame N-1 you're probably rendering on top of frame N-2 or N-3.

Comment: @solidpixel no, I did not factor that. Only KHR_partial_update required it but I was not sure how to use it, so the queried value was left unused.  How would you suggest I should use it? Is it needed even when only  KHR_swap_buffers_with_damage is used?

Comment: Read the "Buffer damage example (EGL_KHR_partial_update)" part of the KHR_partial_update extension.

Comment: TLDR: Your partial updates must factor in the buffer age, because that determines what you are actually rendering on top of.

Comment: @Vijju123 if solidpixel answered your question, please share as an answer to yourself the final solution. If it isn't solved,  I wonder if there are other tags you can add to this question to get more eyes on it. In general, it is always helpful to post lines of code (copy & paste text not an image) for people to help.

Comment: @Mugabo - While I made some progress, there are still things puzzling me which is why I didn't share anything as final answer.  While its true that after factoring in buffer age (was always 2 for my double buffer use-case), I was able to get correct output, I see absolutely no perf gain from this v/s where I would do a complete update (eg- redraw redraw blue background and draw rect on it). I even tried a heavy scenario of rendering 100 rectangles of size 500x500 but the perf was same. I will try to get some code in the question. Any recommendations on tags?

Comment: @solidpixel sorry for bothering you, but I will be really grateful if you can have a look at my above comment and the (pseudo) code snippet I updated in the question. Am I missing some step here due to which I am not seeing any difference in performance of partial and full updates?

Comment: No worries at all. We're all here to help each other. I am not very familiar with OpenGL ES, but I can help ensure that people with the expertise you need see this question. I will add some tags.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately I decided to stick with using EGL_BUFFER_PRESERVE because I couldn't get any perf improvement in using the eglSetSurfaceDamage and eglSwapBuffersWithDamage APIs. I was not able to find a clue either on why it was so.

If anyone is able to find a reason, I'd be most happy to know! Till then, I decided its worth more looking at other areas of optimization than this.